# XML with LINQ without XPath

Tags: xml, linq

I have an object structure I have deserialized from XML - but I'm wanting to use it with LINQ. Is there any way I can add this capability to a normal object structure without the hassle of XPath stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's already deserialized, you can just use linq to objects. Otherwise you can use linq to xml, which is slightly more friendly than XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There is no special requirements on the XML for linq to XML, you can easily use your serialised XML, simply use the classes from system.xml.linq

In particular XElement / XDocument.

i.e.

```
XElement xe = XElement.Parse(**yourXML**);

from x in xe.Descendants("someElement")
     select .....
```